# Remove all events that were imported into my calendar a few days ago

Tags: google-calendar

I imported an ICS file to my Google Calendar a few days ago using **[Settings > Import & Export](https://calendar.google.com/calendar/u/0/r/settings/export)** :

[image]

I'd like to remove all the events that were imported from the ICS file. Is it possible to undo the import now?

The imported events don't have common keywords or other elements that would allow me to automatically find all of them at once. I know what was contained in the ICS file but I would rather not have to manually delete the imported events individually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Luckily, there is some identifying information you can key off.

1. Each event has a `LAST-MODIFIED` field and assuming you haven't made changes since the import, they will share similar `LAST-MODIFIED` values.
2. Also, if you export the calendar, the most recently created/imported events will be at the end of the ICS file and it should be relatively easy to identify and delete the ones from the import.

Probably best to

1. Export the calendar
2. In a text editor, delete the events you no longer want from the ICS file.  Each event's data is within `BEGIN:VEVENT` and `END:VEVENT` tags.
3. Import the updated ICS to a **new** Google calendar
4. Verify everything is working properly in the new calendar
5. Again,  verify everything is okay
6. Delete the old calendar